# Problem with Vue Router when changing parameters of a view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router

I am making a website with vue.js and PHP 7. It is a website of a communication medium where you can view articles.

I have a home view where I call the back when it is created and get all the items. So far everything perfect. The problem is the following:

In the app view, I have a navigation-drawer where every time the view is created I call the back and show all the categories of articles there are.

```
<v-navigation-drawer
              v-model="drawer"
              app
              dark
              temporary
              clipped
              color="secondary"
              v-if="this.user.tipo == null"
      >
          <v-list
                  dense
          >
              <v-list-item-group
                      active-class="success"
              >
                  <div class="categorias">


                  <v-list-item v-for="categoria in categorias">
                      <v-list-item-title
                        class="text-center title ma-4"
                        style="text-transform: uppercase;"
                        @click="$router.push({name:'HomeFiltrado', params:{categoria: categoria.nombre}})"
                      >
                          {{categoria.nombre}}
                      </v-list-item-title>
                  </v-list-item>


                  </div>

              </v-list-item-group>
          </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
```

The view where the articles are going to be filtered depending on their category is called 'HomeFiltrado' and there simply every time the view is created I call the back requesting the articles of the category that come as a parameter in the route

```
created() {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            this.movil = true;
        }
        this.obtenerArticulos()
    }
```

The problem comes when I give the menu to the category (for example) POLITICS and once on the route ** / category/policy ** I give another category (for example) Economy, what happens is that the view does not it is updated and it is like the view is not created again nor is it capable of detecting the change of the parameter in the router. I am very lost and I no longer know how to take it. Thanks in advance.

Then I leave you the scripts of the views

**VIEW HOMEFILTRADO**

```
<script>
import KJUR from 'jsrsasign'
import decode from 'jwt-decode'
import axios from 'axios'
import ScaleLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/ScaleLoader'
import router from '@/router'
import {mapActions, mapState} from 'vuex'
import Twitter from "../components/twitter";

export default {
  name: 'HomeFiltrado',
    data(){
      return{
          movil: false,
          articulos: {},
          cargando: false
      }
    },
    components: {Twitter, ScaleLoader},
    created() {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            this.movil = true;
        }
        this.obtenerArticulos()
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(['tweet']),
        async obtenerArticulos(){
            //console.log("obteniendo articulos "+this.$route.params.categoria)
            this.cargando = true;
            let jws = KJUR.jws.JWS; //Objeto para tratar JWT
            let secret = "my-secret-pass"; // Clave privada

            //crear JWT
            let header = {alg: "HS256", typ: "JWT"}; //Cabecera de JWT
            let data = {
                    id: '',
                    func: 'filtrarArticulos',
                    autor: '',
                    fecha: '',
                    categoria: this.$route.params.categoria,
                    estado: ''
            };

            let jwt = jws.sign("HS256", header, data, {utf8: secret}); //Firma de JWT

            let formd = new FormData();
            formd.append("jwt", jwt)

            let response = await axios.post(this.HOST+'server/api.php', formd)
            let datos = response.data


            if (datos.status) {
                //verify JWT
                let token = datos.token;
                let isValid = jws.verifyJWT(token, {utf8: secret}, {alg: ["HS256"]})

                if (isValid) { //Valido, decodificamos el jwt
                    let decoded = decode(token)

                    //Comprobar status
                    if (decoded.status) { //Datos como los esperabamos

                        if (decoded.data){ //Si hay articulos
                            this.articulos = decoded.data
                            this.cargando = false
                        }else{ //Si no hay artículos
                            this.cargando = false
                        }

                    } else { //Datos erroneos
                        this.mensaje = 'Upss... prueba otra vez'
                        this.cargando = false
                    }

                } else { //Si no es valido
                    this.mensaje = 'Upss... prueba otra vez'
                    this.cargando = false
                }

            }else{
                if (datos.mensaje !== null){
                    this.mensaje = datos.mensaje;
                }else{
                    this.mensaje = 'Server KO... intentelo de nuevo'
                }
                this.cargando = false
            }
        },
    },
    computed:{
      ...mapState(['HOST'])
    },
}
</script>
```

**index.js router**

```
mport Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  { //VENTANA PRINCIPAL
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: () => import('../views/Home.vue')
  },
  { //VENTANA PRINCIPAL POR CATEGORIA
    path: '/categoria/:categoria',
    name: 'HomeFiltrado',
    component: () => import('../views/HomeFiltrado.vue')
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let user = {
    usuarioID: localStorage.getItem('usuarioID') || null,
    tipo: localStorage.getItem('tipo') || null
  }

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (user.usuarioID !==null && user.tipo !==null) {
      next()
    } else {
      next({name: 'Home'})
    }
  } else if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (user.usuarioID !==null && user.tipo === 'administrador') {
      next()
    } else {
      next({name: 'Administracion'})
    }
  }else{
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})

export default router
```

I leave you the compiled code in a host for you to try what I want to tell you:
https://proyectofinallalo.000webhostapp.com/

Comment:  Can you translate comments to English - some of us are not good in Spanish?

Comment: "Remember that params or query changes won't trigger enter/leave navigation guards. You can either watch the $route object to react to those changes, or use the beforeRouteUpdate in-component guard." https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html.  Also https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1490.  (And probably(?) unrelated, but you use history-mode but your server isn't configured to redirecting urls back to your app)